# What algorithm maps number 27 to BBC

Tags: c, algorithm, combinatorics

To clarify the confusion - I want to write a function that maps a number to the following list of letter combinations.

My question is best illustrated with the following table.

```
A   1
B   2
C   3
AA  4
AB  5
AC  6
BA  7
BB  8
BC  9
CA  10
CB  11
CC  12
AAA 13
AAB 14
AAC 15
ABA 16
ABB 17
ABC 18
ACA 19
ACB 20
ACC 21
BAA 22
BAB 23
BAC 24
BBA 25
BBB 26
BBC 27
```

I want to design a function that is able to map a given number, to the left column of this here table. I've tried assigning numerals to the letters first.

```
A = 0
B = 1
C = 2
```

This allows me form the following table (Cn - Column number, from right to left).

```
C3  C2  C1  Number

        0   1
        1   2
        2   3
    0   0   4
    0   1   5
    0   2   6
    1   0   7
    1   1   8
    1   2   9
    2   0   10
    2   1   11
    2   2   12
0   0   0   13
0   0   1   14
0   0   2   15
0   1   0   16
0   1   1   17
0   1   2   18
0   2   0   19
0   2   1   20
0   2   2   21
1   0   0   22
1   0   1   23
1   0   2   24
1   1   0   25
1   1   1   26
1   1   2   27
```

So this looks like an recursive loop type algorithm, but I can't figure out how to put this down in code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Base-3: 3*3*B + 3*B + C = 27 -> 12B + C = 27, where B=2 and C=3 as given.

Comment: I have to apologize to everyone, my intent is to create a function that maps from numbers to these letter combinations. @n.m.

Comment: @MorganWilde as a general rule, for clarity you should place what you have (the number) on the left, and what you want (the letters) on the right. (I wonder if that's backwards for cultures that read from right to left.)

Comment: @mah point taken, and yes, that's backwards if you read right to left, but I don't, which is why I should've placed the number column to the left. You see, first I was working out the combinations, and then the right column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int toInt(const char *str, int acc) {
    if(*str)
        return toInt(++str, acc * 3 + *str - 'A' + 1);
    else
        return acc;
}

char *fromInt(int n, char *outbuff){
    char* p = outbuff;
    while(n){
        *p++ = 'A' + ((n % 3 == 0)? 3 : n % 3) - 1;
        n = (n - 1) / 3;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return strrev(outbuff);//strrev isn't ANSI C

}

int main(void) {
    char buff[] = "BBC";
    int x = toInt(buff, 0);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%s\n", fromInt(x, buff));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - I need the reverse, not `toInt`, but `fromInt`

Comment: Nice, but the expression `'A' + ((n % 3 == 0)? 3 : n % 3) - 1` is a bit cryptic, conceptually we're just indexing into "CAB" with [ n %3 ]

Comment: That way it is clear, to be sure, but replacement of the table data is required when you generalize.

Answer (score 3):

As whoever the person was (user: n.m.) who wrote the comment that disappeared, this is just base-3 counting, except all numerals are offset by +1. The digits really stand for A=0, B=1, C=2

Hence BBC = ('B'+1)*3^2 + ('B'+1)*3 + ('C'+1) = 2*9 + 2*3 + 3 = 27

The pseudocode for `fromInt()`, Antoine has already given you it. Same idea:

```
char* fromInt(int n) {
  result = ""
  working_val = (n-1)
  while (working_val>0) {
    Prepend to result the digit "CAB"[ working_val % 3 ]
    working_val /= 3
  }
  return result
}
```

Strictly we don't care about catching the special-case 0 which Antoine noted, because your list doesn't have a representation for 0.

Comment: @n-m No it wasn't. You just have to offset each digit by +1.

Comment: @n.m. NO, it isn't wrong. It's the basic principles of an abacus what he is showing.

Comment: Well if you offset *each* digit then it's sort of ternary, but then the digits are 1, 2 and 3, there's no 0. It is not immediately clear how to convert numbers *to* this system.

Comment: @n.m. The digits *really* stand for A=0, B=1, C=2. Think that way and you'll never get confused.

Comment: @smci This pseudo code really doesn't provide the results I've shown in the table above. Since 27 would convert to 4 bits of base 3, where in this table it is BBC.

Comment: @smci Then AA is 00 is 0.

Comment: Ok, then handle the special-case 0 like Antoine showed you. You've already accepted BLUEPIXY's answer so do you expect us all to keep working on it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of base-3 system, but the digits are 1 (A), 2 (B) and 3 (C), there is no 0.

The conversion formula *from* this representation is, as usual,

```
3^n*a_n + 3^(n-1)*a_{n-1} + ... + 3^0*a_0
```

The reverse conversion is just like a regular conversion to base 3, the only difference is that a modified remainder function is used:

```
int modified_remainder(m, n)
{
   int answer = m % n;
   if (answer == 0) answer = n;
   return answer;
}
```

Now given the number `m`, the last digit of its representation would be

```
a_0 = modified_remainder(m, 3)
```

The one before last is

```
m_1 = (m - a_0) / 3; // m-a_0 is always divisible by 3
a_1 = modified_remainder(m_1, 3)
```

The next one is

```
m_2 = (m_1 - a_1) / 3
a_2 = modified_remainder(m_2, 3)
```

and so on. You stop when `m_k < n`.

Try to verify these claims, it's a good exercise.

Comment: I was scribbling a solution, where I would take the difference and div it, but I was missing the case where `mod 3` was `0`. Thanks for the outline of the process, I really appreciate that.